# Format Input to force 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im trying to make my input field force 2 decimal places with a comma, heres a sample when i hit the key "5" six times.

```
0,05
0,55
5,55
55,55
555,55
5555,55
```

i searched a lot, but the best i could do was something like this:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#inputID").on('blur change' , function() {       
          $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2))
       }).trigger('blur');
       </script>
```

is it possible to do?

Comment: Since you seem to have found a way to do it, what is your question?

Comment: the script only change like this:  i type: 100 and it change to 100.00, i want to type 100 and it change to 1.00, and show it WHILE im typing

Comment: What should it show if you type `10`? Anyway, test if the input is in a format that needs to be changed. If it does, change it. E.g. if it doesn't contain a `.`, divide by 100 and call `toFixed()`.

Comment: Is the coma a requirement? Because it usually is the thousand separator and the dot is for decimals.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the decimal point from the input, divide it by `100`, then format it to 2 decimal places.

Use the `input` event so this happens as the user types, not just when they leave the input.

```js
$("#inputID").on('blur change input', function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, input) {
    input = input.replace(/\D/g, '');
    return (input / 100).toFixed(2);
  });
}).trigger('blur');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputID">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way if the coma is a requirement for decimal separator.

Note that the dot will be valid too on user input, be will be changed for a coma on blur.

```js
    $("#inputID").on('blur' , function() {       
      var value = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(",","."));
      $(this).val(value.toFixed(2).replace(".",","))
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inputID">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things to fix before you will be **closer** (*I will come back to this later*) to what you are wanting to do:

1. You are triggering the changes using the `blur` and `change` events, both of which happen after a text input loses focus, **not** as the user is typing.  For what it seems like you are trying to do, the `keyup` event is probably the best option (i.e., the event that fires when the keyboard key is released).
2. You are missing a step in `parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2)` . . . what you have takes in you value and converts it directly to a number (e.g., "5" becomes 5).  What you need to do to get the behavior that you want is to divide that value by 100 (e.g., "5" becomes 0.05).  To do that, change the code to: `(parseFloat($(this).val()) / 100).toFixed(2)`
3. To get the `,` instead of the `.` as the decimal separator, use a string `replace` on the result of that updated code: `(parseFloat($(this).val()) / 100).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')`

**HOWEVER . . .**

You are going to run into a couple of issues once you update the value into the input:

1. Browsers are notoriously inconsistent with their placement of cursors and/or "selection" of the content in a field whose value has been systematically changed, and
2. Once you've changed the value the first time and updated it into the input field, it is going to totally through off your calculation.  For example, "5" gets updated to "0,05", so the next time you press a key, you'll really be entering "0,0055", which will result in "0.00"

Of course there are ways to address these issues, but they are going to cause you lots of headaches before you finally get to something that is cross-browser compatible (this will vary, depending on which browsers you want to support).  You may want to consider sticking with the "post-entry", `blur`/`change` approach, if that is an option.